# using alias to reference result set obtained by unions in a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, subquery, alias

I'm having trouble with this query and can't seem to find a solution on the net. What I'm trying to do is to select rows from several tables after applying unions on them and then insert only those rows into table1, whose col2, and col3(as a pair) are not already present in table1.

```
INSERT INTO [somedbo].[table1](col1, col2, col3, col4) 
    SELECT temptbl.MAX(col1), temptbl.col2, temptbl.col3, (temptbl.col2+' '+temptbl.col3)
      FROM    (
               .
               .
             //sub query with unions. which is working fine.
               .
               .
              ) AS temptbl
      WHERE  not exists(select 1 from temptbl as t where t.col2=table1.col2 AND t.col3=table1.col3)
      GROUP  BY col2, col3
      ORDER  BY col2, col3 ASC
```

I'm using SQL Server 2005, and I'm getting the error: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'temptbl'.

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reference your named subquery `temptbl` in your `WHERE` clause subquery.

[Use table variable instead:](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-table-variables)

```
DECLARE @tmptable TABLE (<table definition>)

INSERT INTO @tmptable
SELECT...
<UNION QUERY>
```

Then use the @tmptable in your query as you are now.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I tried using your solution, it works till it populates the table variable @tmptable, but when I further try to use this table variable in my main query, it says that @tmptbl has not been declared, and I've cross cheked several times that I'm using the same variable name throughout the query

Comment: Well if you are using `@tmptable` and `@tmptabl` as you listed it may be an issue :)  Otherwise make sure they are in the same transaction.  The @tablevariable is only good for the transaction you are running.

Comment: well, my mistake in writing the comment : P , I'm infact using the same variable name. I'm not quite clear what you mean by one transaction(owing to my inexperience obviously). I've written all the queries in one go right after another like: -declare @tablevariable- -populate @tablevariable- -main query- and execute with one command.

Comment: I think what is happening in this case is that when i'm using the `@tmptbl` variable in my main query, I'm using it in a where clause sub-query, so that query runs a new transaction for which the variable '@tmptbl' has not been declared.

Answer (score 1):

Use the WITH clause to create a Common Table Expression. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx